# Using Akka to seperate a Lucene service form a website

Tags: scala, lucene, akka

I'm developing a website with a Lucene backend.  Lucene connects directly to index files, making it difficult to develop the website from machines other than the index machine.  Traditional databases have a server running to provide an intermediary between the raw data and the application.

I would like to create such an intermediary between Lucene and my web application.  On first thought, Akka seems like the right tool, and I think I would use Akka futures or typed actors to perform the call.  However, the Akka Typed Actors page warns:

"A bit more background: TypedActors can very easily be abused as RPC, and that is an abstraction which is well-known to be leaky. Hence TypedActors are not what we think of first when we talk about making highly scalable concurrent software easier to write correctly. They have their niche, use them sparingly."

I think the point is that RPC promotes centralization, but is my plan a good one or an abuse of Akka?

Comment: My advice: Make a proof of concept and evaluate.

Comment: Coming from you this must mean I'm not off base...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use solr? It provides the application to manage your lucene indexes (as it is basically lucene with an application over the top to interact with the data. It would be easier than dealing with actors and it should provide everything you need.

Comment: I'm not sure it would be easier at this point.  We already have a Lucene index.  Can you install Solr over an existing Lucene index?  I have been interested in using Solr in the past, but someone else is handling the Lucene index.

Comment: It is possible, you just need to make sure everything gets mapped correctly and defined in the schema.xml. If your lucene index is less than version 3.0, then there might be some issues (as solr and lucene merged together at 3.x).